# Android Studio Designer could not find class

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I am facing a very strange issue.

I am using [this library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) in order to add material design elements such as float buttons.

All was working well, but suddendly the Android Studio designer started to warn me that `com.gc.materialdesign.view.ButtonFloat` could not be found :

[image]

When I change to `ButtonFlat`, the designer asks to change to `ButtonFloat`, etc.

The strange thing is that in my XML, the class is known and there is no error.

[image]

Additionnaly, the buttons are perfectly showing in the emulator :

[image]

The problematic piece of code is the following :

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloat
    android:id="@+id/buttonFloatTakePicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    materialdesign:animate="true"
    materialdesign:iconDrawable="@mipmap/ic_photo"
    android:onClick="takePhoto" />
```

My build.gradle for this module :

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:0.9.10@aar'
}
```

This is very annoying. I tried to clean and build the project several times. Do you have any idea ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes android studio cannot properly display custom layout tag. At that time, I need to close project and close android studio as well. Then, reopen again. It works for me.